How to match path variables in wiremock urlPathMatching
I have this controller
@RequestMapping(value="/sayhi/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Sting> sayHello(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    //code to say hi
}

I have a wiremock which does urlPathMatching with a value for id - lets say "123" as follows
WireMock.urlPathMatching("/sayhi/123")

and then it returns a response with a body when executed on which I have put asserts. How can I make the urlPathMatching dynamic so that instead of 123 we can send anything and how do I write the HTTP GET call for that

urlMatching will allow you to match the path on a regex but the better way would be to use a urlPathTemplate which would allow you to name the part of the url which is dynamic:
urlPathTemplate("/sayhi/{id}")

Doing it this way allows you to further match the WireMock stub on specific values for the id should you want to.
The documentation for urlPathTemplate is here - https://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/#path-templates
If you can't upgrade to the 3.x verison of WireMock where the path templates were introduced, the regex method will work just fine if all you want to do is match on a variable part of the url:
.urlMatching("/sayhi/([0-9]*)")

If you want to send a GET request to WireMock to test it out I would recomend using curl
curl http://<wiremock_host>:<wiremock_port>/sayhi/123


i cannot update to 3.0+. Is there a way to achieve this on lesser versions

If you can't update to the 3.x release of WireMock then I would stick with the regex matching.  I have updated my answer with an example
